# How to change ordered group of columns, whose names lie within range of values?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with the below dataframe, which contains column variable data for each year in 1997-2010, and a year range described by columns 'min' and 'max'.

I want my values in each year column to be changed to 1 if the year lies  inside the range of min to max. How would I do this?

```
library(tidyverse)

    df <- structure(list(`1997` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1998` = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), `1999` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2000` = c(0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1), `2001` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), `2002` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1), `2003` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), `2004` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1), `2005` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), `2006` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1
), `2007` = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), `2008` = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), 
    `2009` = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), `2010` = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1
    ), min = c(1997, 1998, 2006, 2000, 1997, 2000), max = c(1998, 
    1998, 2010, 2010, 2008, 2010)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", 
"2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", 
"2009", "2010", "min", "max"))
```

I've tried using `mutate_at` from the `dplyr` package and creating a vector to assign to these columns (and manipulate later), but I'm struggling with this angle. How should I change the below call to `funs()` so that I can change all 0s within that range to 1s?

```
 for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if (!is.na(df[i,]$min) & !is.na(df[i,]$max)){
      df[i,] <- df[i,] %>% 
        mutate_at(vars(`1997`:`2010`), funs(min:max))
    }
  }
```

Comment: Interesting question. I hope you wont mind final data.frame showing `TRUE/FALSE` instead of `1/0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be using `sapply` and `mapply` as shown below. I have alsow used `between` function from `dplyr`.

Instead of `0` and `1` my solution shows `FALSE/TRUE`. Hope that is fine with OP.

```
#df has been taken from OP
sapply(names(df)[1:(ncol(df)-2)], 
      function(x)mapply(between, as.numeric(x), df$min, df$max)) %>%
       as.data.frame() %>% cbind(df[,c("min","max")])

   1997  1998  1999  2000  2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  2006  2007  2008  2009  2010  min  max
1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 1997 1998
2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 1998 1998
3 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 2006 2010
4 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 2000 2010
5  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE 1997 2008
6 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 2000 2010
```